# Can I forbid a particular application to display pop-up notifications?

Tags: notification, awn

I have installed AWN with a weather applet and it annoys me by complaining that it can't connect to the Internet (saying "network error in weather") frequently. Despite the fact my Internet connection is ok and the applet works just fine actually (which means it manages to reach the server and update the data as frequently as needed). Needless to say I don't really care if it fails to update occasionally.

It seems to be using the common Ubuntu desktop pop-up  system to display its complains. Can I block it? Unfortunately I couldn't find an option in th applet itself.

Comment: Though not a generic solution, I've found a solution for my particular case here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10776305&postcount=3 - it is to comment the line (#240: "self.notification.show()") popping the notification up in `/usr/share/avant-window-navigator/applets/weather/weather.py`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Recent Notifications Applet](https://launchpad.net/~jconti/+archive/recent-notifications), that has **an option to blacklist applications within the applet**. For example if you get a lot of notifications in Pidgin, simply right click a Pidgin notification in Recent Notifications and select "Blacklist Pidgin" - the same goes for any application. If you want to remove an application from the blacklist, right click the Recent Notifications applet and uncheck the app you want to remove from the "Blacklist" tab:

[image]

Add the Recent Notifications PPA and install the applet in Ubuntu using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/recent-notifications
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install recent-notifications
```